# NPM :Cannot find module 'bcrypt'

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt, npm-install

I am getting error Cannot find module 'bcrypt' in nodejs application,I have tried to install it using npm install bcrypt but still getting the issue.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\achraf\Desktop\crud\cruds\api\models\Todo.js:9:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\include-all\index.js:129:29
at Array.forEach (native)
at requireAll (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\include-all\index.js:44:9)
at buildDictionary (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-build-dictionary\index.js:68:14)
at Function.module.exports.optional (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-build-dictionary\index.js:160:9) { [Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Comment: Where/how did you intall bcrypt?

Comment: @SterlingArcher like that : npm  install bcrypt --save

Comment: @SterlingArcher but when i see in node_modules i can't find the folder bcrypt after instaling

Answer (score 4):

`bcrypt` needs to be built natively. If you don't feel comfortable building it with c++ compiler, I suggest you take a look at the `bcrypt-nodejs` module. It basically does the same thing more easily:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
```

**example:**

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      if (err) return err;

      bcrypt.hash(attrs.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
        attrs.password = hash;            
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ****npm install bcrypt**** command can't resolve the issue for me.

I Try below commands and my issue **resolved**.

```
 npm install node-gyp -g
 npm install bcrypt -g
 npm install bcrypt -save
```

Answer (score 1):

This is solved my problem

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try "bcrypt-nodejs".  So `npm install bcrypt-nodejs --save`

Answer (score 0):

check bcrypt Compatibility from this https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt. mine was node 12.0.0 so i have to run "npm install bcrypt@3.0.6"